# PHP Parse.com query error

Tags: php, api, runtime-error, parse-platform

I don't know how many of you are familiar with the parse.com platform, but I am utilizing the third party php library that is linked on their website and I am running into a couple problems.

Link: [Parse.com PHP Library](https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library)

I am trying to query my db but it keeps returning `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.` From what I can see my code is correct but the error originates from one of the files included in the library.

Here is my code thus far:

```
function storeInParseDB ($message, $unit) {

    $parse = new parseQuery($class = 'PushNotifications');
    $parse->whereEqualTo('unit', $unit);
    $result = $parse->find();

    echo "RESULT: ";
    print_r($result);
}
```

Code that is throwing the error:

```
private function checkResponse($response,$responseCode,$expectedCode){
        //TODO: Need to also check for response for a correct result from parse.com
        if($responseCode != $expectedCode){
            $error = json_decode($response);
            $this->throwError($error->error,$error->code);
        }
        else{
            //check for empty return
            if($response == '{}'){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return json_decode($response);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you point out the erroneous line?

Comment: line 176 which is: $this->throwError($error->error,$error->code); I thought I read something somewhere stating it had to do with the json_decode function...

Comment: https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library/issues/30

Comment: It seems this error will be thrown if json_decode returns null.

Comment: Which it is because I have added a print_r($response) just above it, and it is empty. So I don't know if it has to do with XAMPP or what....

Comment: Paste a var dump of the response. eg: var_dump($response) within the if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running the following code after cloning https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library.git - created a parseConfig.php file with appid, restkey and masterkey as decribed in the readme.

I created a new Class in the Parse Data Browser with a single column "unit" of type string and added one row to it, unit = test.

```
<?php

include 'parse.com-php-library/parse.php';

function storeInParseDB ($message, $unit) {
        $parse = new parseQuery('PushNotifications');
        $parse->whereEqualTo('unit', $unit);
        $result = $parse->find();

        echo "RESULT: ";
        print_r($result);
}

storeInParseDB('hi', 'test');
```

As you can see I get the desired output back, make sure you have setup your parseConfig.php file correctly.

```
RESULT: stdClass Object
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [unit] => test
                    [createdAt] => 2013-01-21T14:57:26.613Z
                    [updatedAt] => 2013-01-21T14:57:26.613Z
                    [objectId] => 0uiYuJcRYY
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Works fine using MAMP, but for some reason, on a Windows Machine using XAMPP the json_decode function screws it up.